# Facebook custom login button swift 3: bug

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login, swift3

I have a custom button for facebook login

here is the code for it:

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    print("hello")
    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], from: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
print("logging in")
    }
}
}
```

The bug  goes like this... the first time you load the app on the phone, you have to press the login button twice so that it starts to work.. After that it works everytime with  no exceptions.. has anyone encoutered anything like that.. it started happening when I upgraded to swift 3...

Comment: Have you tried logging the `error` in the completion handler to see if it's returning anything?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this:

```
fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
```

with this:

```
fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: [.PublicProfile, .Email, .UserFriends]
```

Comment: Is this using the standard 'FBSDKLoginKit' framework or the new dedicated Swift framework?

Comment: its using the new one

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out: you have to call the login manager outside the action button, as a global variable